# Bigquery - Best way to transpose rows into multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I have data in below format

| CustomerID | ID | Year | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1477 | 2022 | True |
| 1000 | 1477 | 2021 | True |
| 1000 | 1474 | 2022 | Credit |
| 1000 | 1474 | 2021 | Debit |
| 1000 | 1464 | 2022 | Total Amount |
| 1000 | 1464 | 2021 | Net Amount |

I would like to transpose this data for a particular Customer ID at each ID level for each year. Below is the expected Output

| CustomerID | Year | ID_1477 | ID_1474 | ID_1464 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2022 | True | Credit | Total Amount |
| 1000 | 2021 | True | Debit | Net Amount |

Below is the query I have written to get this. I basically performed a self join and extracted the required elements into separate columns

```
SELECT 
ele_1477.CustomerID,
ele_1477.Year,
ele_1477.value as ID_1477,
ele_1474.value as ID_1474,
ele_1464.value as ID_1464
FROM 
(select * from table where id=1477 ) ele_1477
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from table where id=1474 ) ele_1474 ON ele_1477.CustomerID=ele_1474.CustomerID and ele_1477.Year=ele_1474.Year
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from table where id=1464 ) ele_1464 ON ele_1477.CustomerID=ele_1464.CustomerID and ele_1477.Year=ele_1464.Year
```

But my question here is, I am not sure how effective this query is. I have another 150 set of IDs for a CustomerID that needs to be transposed. Does that mean should i do a self join 150 times? Looking for a best possible solution to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) and a [dynamic SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) for your purpose.

For your sample data, you can pivot your table like below.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM sample_table 
 PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(Value) ID FOR ID IN ('1477', '1474', '1464'));
```

> I have another 150 set of IDs for a CustomerID that needs to be transposed.

And also you can use *EXECUTE IMMEDIATE* instead of writing down 150 IDs in your real data.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM sample_table PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(Value) ID FOR ID IN ('%s'))
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT ID, "','") FROM sample_table));
```

###### Query results of above two queries

[image]